# Cannot CREATE/DELETE Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am trying to re-create a trigger which I had previously created and deleted.

Deletion SQL:

```
DROP TRIGGER openitdb.trgLicenseInsert;
```

Deletion Error:

> Error Code: 1360. Trigger does not exist

Creation SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trgLicenseInsert
AFTER UPDATE ON SoftwareLicenseDetails
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO audithistory (audit_date, audit_field, audit_oldvalue, audit_changelog_fk, audit_newvalue, audit_assetid_fk) VALUES (Now(),'Software License Details', (SELECT Title FROM SoftwareTypes WHERE ID = (SELECT SoftwareNameFK
FROM SoftwareLicenseDetails
WHERE  ComputerFK=new.ComputerFK
ORDER BY ID Desc
LIMIT 1)), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), 'License Added',new.ComputerFK);

END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Creation Error:

> Error Code: 1359. Trigger already exists

The trigger does not show up in MySQL Workbench but somehow it is marked as already existing.

[image: SoftwareLicenseDetails table information]

`SHOW TRIGGERS` :

[image]

How can I solve this issue? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

**I tried combining both triggers but I am getting an error on line 6 (IF new.Flag = 0 ..)**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trgSoftwareLicenseDetails
AFTER UPDATE ON SoftwareLicenseDetails
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF new.Flag = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO audithistory (audit_date, audit_field, audit_oldvalue, audit_changelog_fk, audit_newvalue, audit_assetid_fk) VALUES (Now(),'Software License Details', (SELECT Title FROM SoftwareTypes WHERE ID = 
    (SELECT SoftwareNameFK FROM SoftwareLicenseDetails
    WHERE  ComputerFK=new.ComputerFK
    ORDER BY ID Desc
    LIMIT 1)), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), 'License Added',new.ComputerFK);
FROM SoftwareLicenseDetails
WHERE  ComputerFK=new.ComputerFK
ORDER BY ID Desc
LIMIT 1)), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), 'License Added',new.ComputerFK);
ELSE IF new.Flag = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO audithistory (audit_date, audit_field, audit_oldvalue, audit_changelog_fk, audit_newvalue, audit_assetid_fk) VALUES (Now(),'Software License Details', 'N/A', (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), 'License Deleted',old.ComputerFK);
END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Maybe problem into Workbench? Try make this in mysql console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the show triggers command trgLicenseDelete trigger is attached to after update event. However, you try to create trgLicenseInsert by attaching it to the same event (after update), therefore mysql considers the trgLicenseInsert trigger a duplicate, even though their names are different. Obviously, you cannot drop a trigger with a name that does not exist.

If both triggers need to run after update, then I suggest you to merge their functionality into a single trigger or you need to attach the 2 triggers to different events.

However, probably you are using an old version of mysql, since newer versions should produce different error message if the duplication is due to same event, not same name, see [mysql bug 10946](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10946)

Comment: I tried to combine both triggers into 1, but I am getting an error on line 6. Kindly see updated question with new code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a different question. You should raise it separately.